# nested macros in C _generic macro

Tags: c, pointers, generics, macros, parameter-passing

I'm currently making a small SIMD vector/matrix library in C. I'm looking to use the _generic macro feature in C11 to make function calls always take vector(__m128) arguments as pointers. Is there any way to have the _generic macro call another macro if a non-pointer argument is given and then have that macro append "&" to the argument so it is passed by reference?

Here is an example of my current code:

```
typedef __m128 vec4;
typedef __m128* vec4_t;

vec4_t vec4_new(vec4_t in); // dynamically allocates vec4 and copies "in"

#define vec4_print(X, Y) _Generic((X), __m128: vec4_print_val, __m128*: vec4_print_ptr) (X,Y)

void vec4_print_val(vec4 v, FILE* out);
void vec4_print_ptr(vec4_t v, FILE* out);
```

Basically what I'm asking is if there's any way to ensure the vec4_print_ptr function is always called and the first argument is converted to a pointer if necessary.

Additionally please say if I'm going about it in the wrong way, but my goal is to relieve users from having to treat vec4 pointers and values differently when using them as arguments and ensure that vec4 is always passed by reference in functions using this macro.

Modified code:

vec4.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intirn.h>

typedef __m128 vec4;
typedef __m128 * vec4_t;

vec4_t vec4_new(vec4_t in); // dynamically allocates vec4 and copies "in"

#define vec4_print(X, Y) _Generic((X), __m128: vec4_print_ptr(&X,Y), __m128*: vec4_print_ptr(X,Y))
void vec4_print_val(vec4 vec,FILE* out);
void vec4_print_ptr(vec4_t vec,FILE* out);
```

vec4.c

```
#include "vec4.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

vec4_t vec4_new(vec4_t in)
{   
    void* new_vec;
    posix_memalign(&new_vec, 16, sizeof(__m128));

    if(in == NULL) {
        memset(new_vec, 0, sizeof(__m128));
    }
    else
        memcpy(new_vec, in, sizeof(__m128));

    return (__m128*)new_vec;
}

void vec4_print_val(vec4 vec,FILE* out)
{
    float tmp[4];
    _mm_store_ps(tmp, vec);
    assert(tmp != NULL);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        fprintf(out,"%f ", tmp[i]);
    fprintf(out, "\n");
} 

void vec4_print_ptr(vec4_t vec,FILE* out)
{
    float tmp[4];
    _mm_store_ps(tmp, *vec);
    assert(tmp != NULL);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        fprintf(out,"%f ", tmp[i]);
    fprintf(out, "\n");
}
```

main.c

```
#include "vec4.h"

int main(void)
{
    vec4 v1 = _mm_set_ps(5.0f,3.2f,0.3f,1.0f); //stack __m128
    vec4_t v2 = vec4_new(&v1); //dynamic allocated __m128
    vec4_print(v1, stdout);
    vec4_print(v2, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Clang -std=c11 output: https://pastebin.com/Jgm1qZVE

Comment: Probably... get `vec4_print_val` to call `vec4_print_ptr`? (**edit** this is probably wrong)

Comment: Oh, "pass by reference"... so, always `&` it and `*` it if necessary in `vec4_print_ptr`.

Comment: What about `#define vec4_print(X, Y) _Generic((X), __m128: vec4_print_ptr(&X,Y), __m128*: vec4_print_ptr(X,Y))`? (didn't try so I'm not sure if it works)

Comment: But vec4_print_val will be creating a copy of "v" so it would be unable to pass-on the address of the original argument as it only has a copy. Am I right in my thinking?

Comment: @user202729 tried modifying the _generic macro like above, doesn't seem to work

Comment: It works for me as long as you always pass a lvalue. What is your (modified) code? ([edit] please)

Comment: Now I have to guess what's there inside your `vec4_init` functions (they're mostly unrelated, remove them entirely for a [mcve]) and `#include<stdio.h>`. Also --

Comment: with some modifications, [it works](https://tio.run/##ZZHfTsIwFMbv@xQnEEm71MEAb5x6p8bEB4AYs8z@0SbQLl03IYRnny0FnNKbk36/r/1OT9n1J2NdN1SarRou7mrHlUm/HhBy20pwIUFpB61g8/yPkhy0wuUIDb2mtIhCZT3FCwpLAsWz0MIqhvGC0HDqtucpKmfxaEGXESUXLCCCWqP4fxKTg0qfXl4fEzCNIzt5MEjsN3TwdsXfYUAT7yH53jc5HktjgYu10bWzpVNGQ9XYytSiBqNXWxRujUlKK4flypQOShrrx7GyY@VkZ4VrrIYy36PfhuaFFt@nBjdn08abUBjbulQahzcRtEPgV0zN4L4XfZNOJJ2lU0kn6UzSzG9JfnaHoOnJH9JGbdbH8QfajIL/yzCZSzbtsQM8tjnJ0b7rfgA) for me, despite the warnings. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting passing incompatible types. From the error I can see that the & operator in the _generic macro isn't being applied to v1 and its still trying to pass a vec4 to vec4_print_ptr

Comment: [mcve] please. I can't reproduce your problem.